# Android N use Android.mk build BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY can't generate classes.jar

Tags: java, android, jar, build, android.mk

At Android N open source project, i want to generate my classes.jar use Android.mk,but not.Below is my Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := mysdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,$(SDK_BASE_JAVA_SRC_DIRS))

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

On Android M/L will generated classes.jar. I try to close JACK, compilation failed however.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ave get a method that add BUILD_DROIDDOC after BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY.Then use make mysdk-docs will generate classes.jar file.